# How do I combine these two batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to combine these two batch files. The first .bat file gets information about the version of Microsoft Office installed on a computer, the second gets information about the computer and sends it to a file on the network. I need to combine these files so that all of this information is going into the same file on the network.

The first .bat file

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 


for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%O in ('ftype ^|findstr /r /I "\\OFFICE[0-9]*" 2^>nul') do ( 
    set "tokens=%%~O" 
 goto END_TOKENS 
) 
:END_TOKENS 


for %%P in (%tokens%) do ( 
 set "officePath=%%~dpP" 
 for %%V in ("!officePath:~0,-1!") do ( 
 set "officeVersion=%%~nV" 
 goto END_OFFICEPATH 
 ) 
) 
:END_OFFICEPATH 


REM Check Office "Version" 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office11" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2003 
) 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office12" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2007 
) 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office14" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2010 
) 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office15" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2013 
) 


if "%officeVersion%" == "" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office is not installed 
    goto END 
) 


REM Check Office "Bitness" 
set keyName="HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office" 
set valueName="" 


FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %keyName%`) DO ( 
    set valueName=%%A 
) 


if defined valueName ( 
    @echo Microsoft Office is 32-bit 
) else ( 
set keyName="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office" 
    set valueName="" 
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %keyName%`) DO ( 
    set valueName=%%A 
    ) 


    if defined valueName ( 
    @echo Microsoft Office is 64-bit 
    ) 
) 


:END 



endlocal 



echo Completed! Thank you!

pause
```

The second .bat file

```
 @echo off

net use Q: \\example\example



(systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain"

ipconfig | findstr IPv4

systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model"

echo Service Tag: 
wmic bios get serialnumber

systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"os version"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type"


echo %username%) > Q:\example\%computername%.txt


net use Q: /delete

echo Completed! Thank you!
```

Comment: `>` will write to a new file, while `>>` will append. Having said that, your first bat could `...> toTheFile` and your second batch would `...>> ToTheSameFile`. The path of the said `file` could be passed along as a cmd line parameter and retrieved using your desired flavor of `%1`

Comment: What is stopping you from copying and pasting the code from one script to the other script?

Comment: ^ That was the idea but I don't know enough about batch scripting to make it work properly :-)

Comment: _Side note:_ instead of running the slow command `systeminfo` multiple times you could do `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Host Name:" /C:"Domain:" ...` to have all lines of interest extracted at once (returned in the same order like output by `systeminfo`, if that does not disturb)...

Answer (score 0):

Here they are, combined and working together towards the same "report" file defined in `savePath`..

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
set savePath="c:\temp\myfile.txt"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%O in ('ftype ^|findstr /r /I "\\OFFICE[0-9]*" 2^>nul') do ( 
    set "tokens=%%~O" 
 goto END_TOKENS 
) 
:END_TOKENS 


for %%P in (%tokens%) do ( 
 set "officePath=%%~dpP" 
 for %%V in ("!officePath:~0,-1!") do ( 
 set "officeVersion=%%~nV" 
 goto END_OFFICEPATH 
 ) 
) 
:END_OFFICEPATH 


REM Check Office "Version" 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office11" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2003  > %savePath%
) 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office12" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2007  > %savePath%
) 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office14" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2010  > %savePath%
) 
if "%officeVersion%" == "Office15" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office 2013  > %savePath%
) 


if "%officeVersion%" == "" ( 
    echo Microsoft Office is not installed > %savePath%
    goto END 
) 


REM Check Office "Bitness" 
set keyName="HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office" 
set valueName="" 


FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %keyName%`) DO ( 
    set valueName=%%A 
) 


if defined valueName ( 
    @echo Microsoft Office is 32-bit  > %savePath%
) else ( 
set keyName="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office" 
    set valueName="" 
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %keyName%`) DO ( 
    set valueName=%%A 
    ) 


    if defined valueName ( 
    @echo Microsoft Office is 64-bit  > %savePath%
    ) 
) 


:END 



endlocal 




net use Q: \\example\example


(systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain"

ipconfig | findstr IPv4

systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model"

echo Service Tag: 
wmic bios get serialnumber

systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"os version"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory"

systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type"


echo %username%) >> %savePath%


net use Q: /delete

echo Completed! Thank you!
```